# What is this notation, similar to the binomial coefficient?

Tags: notation, stirling-numbers

I've come across this notation:

$$\left\{\begin{eqnarray}n\\m\end{eqnarray}\right\}$$

The only other info I have about this notation is that $\left\{\begin{eqnarray}4\\2\end{eqnarray}\right\}=7$

What's the name of this notation and what is it used for?

Thanks

Comment: I find it slightly disappointing that with the vast knowledge we have here, all three answers do little more than link to wikipedia.

Comment: There is a [Stirling numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stirling-numbers), which I added to your post. If you are interested in them then you might want to browse through the questions there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you're using [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind), where $\displaystyle{n\brace k}$ denotes the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets.

You can use `{n\brace k}` to produce ${n\brace k}$ and `\displaystyle{n\brace k}` to produce $\displaystyle{n\brace k}$.

An example of a 'real world' application of these numbers can be found in [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/773548/39599) which asks how many rooks can be placed on a triangular chessboard so that none of them are attacking each other.

Comment: Any chance of an application? It would make your answer complete...(for example, they can be used to find certain generating sets of certain semigroups).

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer by providing a real life example of its usage? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

[Stirling numbers of second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), the number of partitions of a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets.